# Getting VMAF metrics along with others like PSNR

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg installed along with libvmaf. While I am able to get just the VMAF score by

```
   ./ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf -f null -
```

But if I try to get VMAF and PSNR by

```
   ./ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf="psnr=1" -f null -
```

then I still get only VMAF. There is no PSNR that is printed out. Same with other metrics like SSIM or MS_SSIM. Can anyone explain why ? Also, where are the VMAF logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Except for the aggregate VMAF score, all other metrics are only published, per-frame, in the logfile.

```
ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf=psnr=1:log_path=/home/vmaf_log.txt -f null -
```

Comment: Thank you - that works. The only thing that I am still struggling with is enabling of confidence interval. Tried with "./ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf="enable_conf_interval=1" -f null -" but I get an error saying that "Error while filtering: Invalid argument"

Comment: It's a new option - get a git build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the ffmpeg log.
the order is `2>log_path`. You can try to add from last.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf=psnr=1:log_path=/home/vmaf_log.txt -f null -` command, you might see **Error Message** : "The "psnr" option is deprecated: use feature='name=psnr'."

So, you can execute below command:

> ffmpeg -i testfile -i reffile -lavfi libvmaf=feature='name=psnr':log_path=vmaf_log.txt -f null -